# CONVERT_TZ not working properly during winter/summer time change hour

Tags: mysql, timezone

In Paris (timezone Europe/Paris) the timezone offset change on 2016-03-27 at 2:00am. Timezone is before at UTC+1 and after at UTC+2.

Mysql function CONVERT_TZ not work if you give a time during the change : between 2016-03-27 02:00:01 and  2016-03-27 02:59:59

Example :

SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 02:18:29', 'Europe/Paris', "UTC"                ) === '2016-03-27 01:00:00'

And funny : 
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 01:00:00', 'UTC', "Europe/Paris"                ) === '2016-03-27 03:00:00'

I have to convert a mysql database with date in many timezone to a new database with all date directly in UTC timezone (safe), with this issue some date will be wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Given an "invalid" local time, MySQL's `CONVERT_TZ` function advances it to the next valid local time before converting it.  Since your `2:18:29` value really does not occur on that date in that time zone, it is advanced to `3:00:00` local time, then converted correctly to `1:00:00` UTC.

In the fall, when DST ends in Paris on October 30th 2016, `2:18:29` will occur *twice*.  You'll find that MySQL's `CONVERT_TZ` function chooses the *second* of two occurrences.

This behavior is consistent, and thus saying it doesn't work is incorrect.  It works, it just may not be the behavior *you* would prefer.

Personally, I think in the spring it would be better to skip ahead to `3:18:39` (which converts to `1:18:29` UTC).  I also think in the fall it's better to use the *first* of the two occurrences.  I think that behavior accommodates a larger number of real-world scenarios, but that's just my opinion.

Besides, why do you have invalid times in your data to begin with?  If they are recorded from real events, the time will be skipped on the clock and thus not end up in your database.  So usually, one only has to deal with this when dealing with *calculation* of time, such as a recurring schedule.

Regarding your second example, there's nothing wrong there.  1:00 UTC would indeed be 3:00 in Paris when the time zone offset is UTC+2.