# check if a date is valid in specific timezone mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a lot of date time value stored from all over the world. I have my timezone near this data.
To convert it in UTC, I use `CONVERT_TZ` but for some value, my database is "corrupted" and I have some wrong date time in the specify timezone.
For example, I have "2011-03-27 02:12:00" in timezone "Europe/Paris" which is normally not correct.
 
To identify wrong dates I use

> WHERE date_time != CONVERT_TZ(date_time,"Europe/Paris","Europe/Paris")

What do you think about performance of this type of request ? Do you have better function to check if date is valid ?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Do you have time zone information tables in the mysql database have been created?

Comment: Yes, I set up time zone tables

Comment: Understood. Possible error claims for daylight change, UNIX_TIMESTAMP also marks this issue https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp and you can use it too

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP don't allow me to specify my date in particular timezone. To be clearer, I refer my question to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921848/convert-tz-not-working-properly-during-winter-summer-time-change-hour). I want detect if mysql will consider my date time as invalid